# AddWithValue() isn't accepting DBNull.Value (Exception 0x800A0BB9) - Silverlight - VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, silverlight, parameters, ado

I'm developing an OOB Silverlight application and using the COM Toolkit (http://silverlightcom.codeplex.com), the language is Visual Basic (VB). With this pack, I can connect my app with my Microsoft SQL Server database using ADO.NET. It works, but when I try to insert a null value to a parameter it throws an exception: 0x800A0BB9 (http://prntscr.com/43zwyr).

My code is (I will post the most simple stretch):

```
    Private Const SqlCreateJob As String = "insert into Cargos(Nome_carg, Desc_carg) values(?, ?)"

    Public Shared Sub CreateJob(ByVal j As Job)

        Dim conn As AdoConnection = DbUtil.GetConn
        Dim cmd As AdoCommand = conn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = SqlCreateJob

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nome_carg", j.Name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Desc_carg", j.Desc)

        For Each p As AdoParameter In cmd.Parameters
            If p.Value = Nothing Then
                p.Value = DBNull.Value
            End If
        Next

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

And the class Job:

```
Public Class Job
    Property Code() As Integer
    Property Name() As String
    Property Desc() As String
End Class
```

The value Desc, from Job, can be null. And if I put 
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Desc_carg", DBNull.Value)` it still doesn't work. What can I do? (When the Desc is not null the command works)

The Exception.ToString is here:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0BB9): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0BB9 ---> MS.Internal.ComAutomation.ComAutomationObjectException: The arguments are incorrect, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict.(Source=ADODB.Parameter) (HelpFile=C:\WINDOWS\HELP\ADO270.CHM#1240641) em MS.Internal.ComAutomation.ComAutomationNative.CheckInvokeHResult(UInt32 hr, String memberName, String exceptionSource, String exceptionDescription, String exceptionHelpFile, UInt32 exceptionHelpContext) em MS.Internal.ComAutomation.ComAutomationNative.Invoke(Boolean tryInvoke, String memberName, ComAutomationInvokeType invokeType, ComAutomationInteropValue[] rgParams, IntPtr nativePeer, ComAutomationInteropValue& returnValue) em MS.Internal.ComAutomation.ComAutomationObject.InvokeImpl(Boolean tryInvoke, String name, ComAutomationInvokeType invokeType, Object& returnValue, Object[] args) em MS.Internal.ComAutomation.ComAutomationObject.Invoke(String name, ComAutomationInvokeType invokeType, Object[] args) em System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.AutomationMetaObjectProvider.TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, Object value) em System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation.AutomationMetaObjectProviderBase.<.cctor>b__3(Object obj, SetMemberBinder binder, Object value) em CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 ) em System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) em CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int32 ) em ComToolkit.Data.AdoParameter.set_Type(DbType value) em ComToolkit.Data.AdoParameter..ctor(Object adoParameter, String name, Object value) em CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , String , Object ) em System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute4[T0,T1,T2,T3,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3) em CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object , String , Object ) em ComToolkit.Data.AdoCommand.CreateParameter(String name, Object value) em ComToolkit.Data.AdoParameterCollection.AddWithValue(String name, Object value) em Corporativo.Dao.CargoDao.AddParameters(AdoCommand cmd, Cargo c) em Corporativo.Dao.CargoDao.CriarCargo(Cargo c) em Corporativo.UCCadCargos.Create()
```

And the .Message:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0BB9

Comment: Please copy/paste your exception instead of posting a link, so that this question may help others in the future if the link no longer works.

Comment: Does both `Nome_carg` and `Desc_carg` accepts null value?

Comment: No, only Desc_carg, but I'm using that For each because I have identical Sub's for more than 20 parameters, and several are nullable.

Comment: If I use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Desc_carg", DBNull.Value)` it does not work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `AddWithValue` if the value is, or van be, NULL.  `AddWithValue` infers the data type of the parameter from the value but, if the value is NULL, a type cannot be inferred.  You should be using `Add` in such cases, specifying the data type explicitly and setting the `Value` property.